# Getting 2 canvas images to appear with 1 button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get multiple canvas images to appear with 1 button press. I can get one image to work perfect, but the second one I can't. **I know that ID's have to be unique and that only the first canvas will have an image currently.**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg">
            <img src="Assets/Images/background.png" alt="background">   
        </div>
        <section class="content">

            <img id="taxi" src="Assets/Images/PV.png" width="106" height="53">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="106" height="53"
            style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; position:absolute; left:510px;top:117px;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="106" height="53"
            style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; position:absolute; left:310px;top:117px;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

            <p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("taxi");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,53);
  }
```

I know that I can get it work by changing one the `id="myCanvas"` in the HTML and repeating the current lines in the script to get it to work. But the end web page will have lots of canvas' and I didn't want to keep repeating the javascript code.

Is there a simple way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: HTML elements cannot have the same id. Use class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements cannot have the same id. You'll need to retrieve your elemnts some other way. There are many ways; `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelectorAll`, ... etc.

Use `querySelectorAll(".content > canvas");` This will select all **direct** children that are canvas elements in the element that has the class of "content" (which in this case is your section element).

```
function myCanvas() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".content > canvas").forEach(c=>{
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("taxi");
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,53);
    });
}
```

Basic example:

```js
function myCanvas() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".content > canvas").forEach(c=>{
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("taxi");
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,53);
    });
}
```

```html
<section class="content">

  <img id="taxi" src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/899287106/45820b5b6bba46c7fcd853a46d554a34?v=1" width="106" height="53">
  <canvas width="106" height="53" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; position:absolute; left:510px;top:117px;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <canvas width="106" height="53" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; position:absolute; left:310px;top:117px;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

  <p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, will this select ALL canvas elements on page?

Comment: @JackU this will select all canvases in the element that has the class "content" (so in this example, all canvas elements in your section element). If you'd like to select every single canvas on your page then I would recommend using `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');`